# unable to connect to datasource because of sql exception- ATG app

Tags: sql, exception, weblogic, atg

I am trying to deploy an **ATG application** in the weblogic Admin server for development. But it says the following error:
"unable to connect to datasource because of sql exception: Internal error: Cannot obtain XAConnection weblogic.common.resourceException: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found" 
[ screenshot]: ***https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptj8l.jpg***  I'm new to these ATG and weblogic technologies. So please guide me to the solution.

Comment: Is your database set up properly? Can you go to the `Data Sources-><your source>->Monitoring->Testing` tab and see if the connection works when testing there? Also, maybe you are running out of connections. See here: http://staranalytics.com/support/kb-article/tnsno-appropriate-service-handler-found-using-oracle-10g-express/

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow ATG Installation guide very carefully, especially, if you are newbie to ATG.

Perhaps, you miss step of configuration your ATG installation using CIM.

Check this paper - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/CRS.10-2/ATGCRSInstall/ATGCRSInstall.pdf